# Getting a debug error when installing Cocoapods / Pods?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

When i'm in console and write `Pod install` it installs it, how ever when i open my xcode file and clicking on the pods folder i only see 2 files.
Both somekind of debugging error

> "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited)
>   "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Canvas" GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS =
>   $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited)
>   '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks' OTHER_CFLAGS =
>   $(inherited) -iquote
>   "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Canvas/Canvas.framework/Headers"
>   OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "Canvas" PODS_BUILD_DIR =
>   $BUILD_DIR PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR =
>   $PODS_BUILD_DIR/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) PODS_ROOT =
>   ${SRCROOT}/Pods"

Does anyone know how to fix it, by the way i'm on MacOS Seirra, Xcode 8 but with deployment target 1.9.3

Comment: Run `pod update` and tell me what you've got

Comment: do you still need help here?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can reinstall them by removing your dependencies from your `PodFile` then run `pod install`, after that re-add them again then run `pod install` and it will reinstall them. Hope that works

Comment: So i just remove the Podfile i've created inside xcode?

Comment: No, remove the dependencies like `pod 'GooglePlaces' ` remove that then run pod install and it will remove these dependencies then add them again and do a  pod install that will cleanly install them again

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following the steps:

- I closed Xcode
- Run:

```
cd ios && pod deintegrate
pod install
xed
```

With this, the project run without the errors